# How to deploy my chatbot in bluemix itself to be accessible via a web url?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, ibm-cloud-tools, watson-discovery

I just built my first basic chatbot on IBM's bluemix using their own tutorial. However, I'm unable to connect the thread of how it gets deployed on bluemix so as to be accessible via web/a url- like the chatbot in this url for example: [chatbot in an url](https://food-coach.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=41847749879914922032494&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1492312719&cm_mc_sid_52640000=1492312719)

Currently, I'm only finding resources to help me put my chatbot in slack, fb messenger, etc. I dont need all that currently, just looking to have it accessible via url.

Thanks

Comment: Push your source code into IBM Bluemix. Which programming language have you used to build it? From Catalog , select runtime of your choice. For eg: Java runtime and then push the WAR/EAR file and connect Watson Conversation service to that application. Once,it is deployed you will be able to access your chatbot using URL

Answer (score 1):

In this case, log in your IBM Bluemix account and you can simple deploy inside IBM Bluemix with `https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=urlfromGithub`

In your case, I recommend for you use [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) from IBM Developers for start only with Conversation Service, this app use only Conversation service.

- You can add `Enviroment Variable` after install this app
- You can simple add inside the code your Credentials and `WORKSPACE_ID`, in this case, in the file `app.js` in line [#42](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L42) for use *your bot created*.
- Or, you can change the `.env` file with your credentials and `WORKSPACE_ID`;

**Deploy conversation simple inside your IBM Bluemix with this** [URL](https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple), this example had all more details about how to use this app.

**Add Enviroment Variable:**

[image]

**Change the** `username` **and** `password` **with YOUR** *Service Credentials* **in line** [#30](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L30)

[image]

**Change your workspace_id:**

```
var workspace = 'awidhawfi-fehguaehgae-faefag-etc-etc';
```

**Imported the workspace:**

- Click the menu icon in the upper right corner of the workspace tile, and then select *View details*.

[image]